# Is there a registry key or group policy to disable the "If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable" warning in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, group-policy, user-interface

In Windows, when you change a file extension, you get a warning

> If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable
>
> Are you sure you want to change it?

Is there a registry key or group policy setting to disable this warning?

If you know of an authoritative reference indicating the warning can't be disabled, please link to it.

I change file extensions frequently and always have to confirm this dialog.